# Conjecture based on limited trail followed by inductive proof

Tags: calculus, induction

My syllabus says:

> recognise situations where conjecture based on a limited trail followed by inductive proof is a useful strategy, and carry this out in simple casses e.g. find the nth derivative of $xe^x$"

Please tell me what it means in simple terms which I can type on google or YouTube to find lectures and excercises to practice and learn this as I have no book or teacher to teach me.

Answer (score 1):

It means try the first few cases; in this case the 1st,2nd,3rd,... derivative, and see if you spot any pattern. After that, try to prove the pattern correct by using induction.

Comment: It is a topic by itself not a single question. And xe^x is an example. I was thinking maybe it is a technique "conjecture based in a limited trail followed by inductive proof." Atleast explain this statement.

Comment: I'm serious. "Limited trail" refers to "first few cases", "conjecture based on that" means "spot a pattern" and "inductive proof" means "prove the pattern correct by induction". It works well when there is a simple closed form for the pattern.